# I need to be able to print the largest record value from txt file using bash

Tags: bash, unix

I am new to bash programming and I hit a roadblock.

I need to be able to calculate the largest record number within a txt file and store that into a variable within a function.

Here is the text file:
student_records.txt

```
12345,fName lName,Grade,email
64674,fName lName,Grade,email
86345,fName lName,Grade,email
```

I need to be able to get the largest record number ($1 or first field) in order for me to increment this unique record and add more records to the file. I seem to not be able to figure this one out.

First, I sort the file by the first field in descending order and then, perform this operation:

```
largest_record=$(awk-F,'NR==1{print $1}' student_records.txt)
echo $largest_record
```

This gives me the following error on the console:

```
awk-F,NR==1{print $1}: command not found
```

Any ideas?  Also, any suggestions on how to accomplish this in the best way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need spaces, and quotes

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{print $1}'
```

The command is `awk`, you need a space after it so bash parses your command line properly, otherwise it thinks the whole thing is the name of the command, which is what the error messages is telling you.

Learn how to use the `man` command so you can learn how to invoke other commands:

```
man awk
```

This will tell you what the `-F` option does:

> The -F fs option defines the input field separator to be the regular expression fs.

So in your case the field separator is a comma `-F,`

What follows in quotes is what you want awk to interpret, it says to match a line with the pattern `NR==1`, NR is special, it is the record number, so you want it to match the first record, following that is the action you want awk to take when that pattern matches, `{print $1}`, which says to print the first field (comma separated) of the line.

A better way to accomplish this would be to use `awk` to find the largest record for you rather than sorting it first, this gives you a solution that is linear in the number for records - you just want the max, no need to do extra work of sorting the whole file:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {max = 0} {if ($1>max) max=$1} END {print max}' student_records.txt
```

For this and other `awk` "one liners" look [here](https://sites.google.com/site/antialamas/awkoneliners).

Answer (score 2):

```
largest=$(sort -r file|cut -d"," -f1|head -1)
```

Comment: +1. I would also suggest adding `-n` to the sort options, just in case some records have exceeded `99999` number...